# How to apply a mask to input password in HTML?

Tags: html, mask

I want create a field password with a mask : "_ _ _ _",

With placeholder attribute the content of field("_ _ _ _") is cleared after the first digit entered.

BUT i need when i type first digit the field become "_ _ *"
seconde digit ->"* _" and so on

Any idea with jquery or HTML5?

Thnaks in advance

Comment: Look at google, he has a lot of answers... http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#inputmask

Comment: Sure, in that case you cannot use the placeholder attribute obviously. Instead you fill the string `_ _ _ _` as value of the input field and implement an event handler reacting on the key events inside the input element. That allows you to modify the content just as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I this code will help you to your problem, Only u have to define your own patter, As for the example i have given the pattern as character/numeric/character numeric/character/numeric.

```css
        input {
  font-family: monospace;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
div {
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}

.shell {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1; }
  .shell span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 3px;
    top: 1px;
    color: #ccc;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: -1; }
    .shell span i {
      font-style: normal;
      /* any of these 3 will work */
      color: transparent;
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden; }

input.masked,
.shell span {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase; }        input {
  font-family: monospace;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
div {
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}

.shell {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1; }
  .shell span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 3px;
    top: 1px;
    color: #ccc;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: -1; }
    .shell span i {
      font-style: normal;
      /* any of these 3 will work */
      color: transparent;
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden; }

input.masked,
.shell span {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase; }
```

```html
<form action="">
  
  
  <div>
    <label for="czc"> Zip Code</label>
    <input id="czc" placeholder="XXX XXX" pattern="\w\d\w \d\w\d" class="masked" 
        data-charset="_X_ X_X" id="zipca" type="text" name="zipcodeca" 
        title="6-character alphanumeric zip code in the format of A1A 1A1" />
  </div>

</form>

<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/masking-input.js" data-autoinit="true"></script>
```